# Label is not appearing in Seaborn distplot

Tags: python, pandas, label, seaborn, density-plot

I am using the `distplot()` function of Seaborn and I am juxtaposing two density plots -- each with a different color in the same plot -- and I want to label them.

I use the argument 'label', referred in the documentation of the function.

My code is:

```
Response4_mask = train_with_response['Response4'] == 1
not_Response4_mask = train_with_response['Response4'] != 1

plt.figure()

sns.distplot(a = train_imp_with_response[Response4_mask]['Family_Hist_4'], hist = True, color = 'red', label = 'Response4')
sns.distplot(a = train_imp_with_response[not_Response4_mask]['Family_Hist_4'], hist = True, label = 'not_Response4')

plt.title('Family_Hist_4')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output is below.  There is no label in it:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add

```
plt.legend()
```

See [documentation for `legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) and matplotlib's [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-legend-guide-py) for more details

before `plt.show()`